# Requests Post UnicodeEncodeError comes up despite encoding with utf-8

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, python-requests

I have seen many topics opened on this subject, yet none of them helped me solve the issue. I have a dataset containing text with lots of different characters. Therefore, I encode the text before I make a POST request using Requests library on Python 2.7.13.

My code is the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# encoding=utf8
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
import json
import requests
text = """So happy to be together on your birthday! ❤ Thankful for real life. ❤ A post shared by Jessica Chastain (@jessicachastain) on Nov 13, 2016 at 5:22am PST"""
textX = json.dumps({'text': text.encode('utf-8')})
r = requests.post('http://####', data=textX,
                      headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'})
print(r.text)
```

The data is sent in JSON format. No matter where I try to encode the text as UTF-8, I'm still getting the following error from Requests.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2764' in
position 42: Body ('❤') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8')
if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.
```

Edit:
Syntax error fixed, but not the cause of the problem

Comment: aren't you missing a closing `)` in `textX = json.dumps({'text': text.encode('utf-8'})` ? Should be causing a syntax error...

Can you post the rest of the traceback: what line is generating the UnicodeError?

Comment: @cowbert, you are right, there was a syntax error, but I got the Unicode error even when the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for `json.dumps` is to generate an ASCII-only string, which eliminates encoding problems.  The error is not using a Unicode string.  Make sure to save the source file in the encoding declared (`#coding=utf8`):

```
# coding=utf8
import json
text = u"""So happy to be together on your birthday! ❤ Thankful for real life. ❤ A post shared by Jessica Chastain (@jessicachastain) on Nov 13, 2016 at 5:22am PST"""
textX = json.dumps({u'text': text})
```

Output:

```
'{"text": "So happy to be together on your birthday! \\u2764 Thankful for real life. \\u2764 A post shared by Jessica Chastain (@jessicachastain) on Nov 13, 2016 at 5:22am PST"}'
```

Comment: Thanks @mark-tolonen from your answer. Although, I get the same output as you do, I still get the following error when I try to post textX
     UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2764' in
position 42: Body ('❤') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8')
if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: @Furkanicus Actually my formatting was incorrect on the output, which suppressed the actual content.  It's fixed now  There isn't a `\u2764` character, but a literal escape code `'\\u2764'` so there wouldn't be a Unicode character in it.  So that seems like a bug somewhere else.  You aren't specifying `latin-1` anywhere.  JSON can be transmitted with escape codes and it will still decode on the other end of the connection when the server processes it.